# RandomForest, how to choose the optimal n_estimator parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, cross-validation

I want to train my model and choose the optimal number of trees. codes are here

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

tree_dep = [3,5,6]
tree_n = [2,5,7]

avg_rf_f1 = []
search = []

for x in tree_dep:
  for y in tree_n:
    search.append((a,b))
    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=tree_n, max_depth=tree_dep, random_state=42)
    rf_scores = cross_val_score(rf_model, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')

    avg_rf_f1.append(np.mean(rf_scores))

best_tree_dep, best_n = search[np.argmax(avg_rf_f1)]
```

the error is in this line

```
rf_scores = cross_val_score(rf_model, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')
```

saying

`ValueError: n_estimators must be an integer, got <class 'list'>.`

wondering how to fix it. Thank you!!!

Comment: take a look at your error message. You have not passed an `int`, you have passed the whole `list`. `rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=y)`

Comment: yes i see. but to be honest i am a really beginner for python. I don't know how to change it.

Comment: I added the answer to the above comment. Or see Piotrek's answer

Comment: should i train number of trees separately? like  rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=2) ;   rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=5);    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=7) ?

Comment: ahhh!! I see. How can I didn't see it!! thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a helper function in scikit-learn called [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) that does just that. It takes a list of parameters values you want to test, and trains a classifier with all possible sets of these to return the best set of parameters.
I would suggest it is a lot cleaner and faster than the nested loop method you are implementing. It is easily extendable to other parameters (just add the desired parameters to your grid) and it can be parallelized.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

params_to_test = {
    'n_estimators':[2,5,7],
    'max_depth':[3,5,6]
}

#here you can put any parameter you want at every run, like random_state or verbosity
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
#here you specify the CV parameters, number of folds, numberof cores to use...
grid_search = GridSearchCV(rf_model, param_grid=params_to_test, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro', n_jobs=4)

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

best_params = grid_search.best_params_ 

#best_params is a dict you can pass directly to train a model with optimal settings 
best_model = RandomForestClassifier(**best_params)
```

As pointed out in the comments, the best model is stored in the `grid_search` object, so instead of creating a new model with:

```
best_model = RandomForestClassifier(**best_params)
```

We can ust use the one in `grid_search`:

```
best_model = grid_search.best_estimator_
```

Comment: `n_cores` should be `n_jobs` in GridSearchCV. Also `best_model` == `grid_search.best_estimator_` is a bit more convenient than passing `best_params` especially if you're using a pipeline etc.

Answer (score 2):

You iterate through the elements of the lists in your loops, but you don't use them inside the loop. Instead of providing an element from the list as `n_estimators` or `max_depth`, you provide the whole list. This should fix it, now in every iteration you take a different combination of the elements from the two lists:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

tree_dep = [3,5,6]
tree_n = [2,5,7]

avg_rf_f1 = []
search = []

for x in tree_dep:
  for y in tree_n:
    search.append((a,b))
    rf_model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=y, max_depth=x, random_state=42)
    rf_scores = cross_val_score(rf_model, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='f1_macro')

    avg_rf_f1.append(np.mean(rf_scores))

best_tree_dep, best_n = search[np.argmax(avg_rf_f1)]
```